# My Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 doesn't have Windows Service in New Project list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services, missing-template

As the title, I want to make a service but I can't find it. When I setup, I didn't choose any extra option and the setup take 5GB space

Answer (score 0):

This template hidden in Templates -> Visual C# -> Windows -> Classic Desktop